# How to SQL join 2 tables, joining their columns and removing column duplicates?

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

*(I'm an SQL beginner)*

I'm joining 2 tables without the keyword "join" (**not** trying to avoid it at all costs). I get a lot of duplicate entries in 1 column that I need to be distinct.

```
tab1: col1, col2, col3, col4
tab2: col1, col2, col3, col4, col5

SELECT a.col1, a.col3, b.col5
FROM tab1 a, tab2 b
WHERE (a.col2 = 'abc') and (a.col3 = b.col3) and (b.col5 = 'def')

result: a.col1, a.col3, b.col5 -- a.col1 must be distinct (like a prim key)
```

**How can I remove the duplicates of the column `a.col1` ?**

`SELECT DISTINCT` didn't work because I need 1 resulting column to become prim key. It makes only the rows distinct. None of the columns I use is the prim key of any of those tables.

Comment: What are the primary keys of the two tables? And how is it possible that `SELECT DISTINCT` return duplicate rows? That is simply not possible.

Comment: Why is it important to you to avoid the keyword *join*?

Comment: @ypercube Sorry, I asked incorrectly. I rephrased as good as I could.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago)

Comment: @marc_s I think it's **waaay** better readable without join keyword. But I'm not trying to avoid it at all costs. I just said that to make you know I didn't forget the join, or whatever (read the very first line of the Q).

Comment: @mini-me with 2 tables, it may be more readable for some people. With 15 tables, no.

Comment: @mini-me: it *might* be more readable (that's debatable), but **(1)** it carries the risk of a cartesian product if you happen to forget the JOIN condition, and **(2)** you're mixing actual `WHERE` clauses with `JOIN` conditions which makes everything a mess, in my opinion. There's a **good reason** why it's been **removed** from the SQL standard more than 20 years ago